# Ошибка iOS Swift: Library not loaded - Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, alamofire, pod

При build проекта на физическом девайсе приложение крашится c ошибкой:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire
  Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/XXXX-B5C4-44BC-AEA6-4BC35E799993/Testovy.app/Testovy
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/XXXX-B5C4-44BC-AEA6-4BC35E799993/Testovy.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/XXX-B5C4-44BC-AEA6-4BC35E799993/Testovy.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire'

    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/XXXX-B5C4-44BC-AEA6-4BC35E799993/Testovy.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire: stat() failed with errno=25
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/XXXX-B5C4-44BC-AEA6-4BC35E799993/Testovy.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/XXXX-B5C4-44BC-AEA6-4BC35E799993/Testovy.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire'

    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/XXXX-B5C4-44BC-AEA6-4BC35E799993/Testovy.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire: stat() failed with errno=1
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/XXXX-B5C4-44BC-AEA6-4BC35E799993/Testovy.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/XXXX-B5C4-44BC-AEA6-4BC35E799993/Testovy.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire'

    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/XXXX-B5C4-44BC-AEA6-4BC35E799993/Testovy.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire: stat() failed with errno=1
```

А на симуляторе все отлично работает

Answer (score 0):

Проблема с ios 13.3.1
https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/3051

Сейчас возникает если использовать бесплатный Apple ID (без лицензии разработчика). Работает если убрать use_frameworks! из подс файла, но может вызвать проблемы с другими фреймворками. Нужно подождать лучшего решения от Apple